# Remove keys with `None` value from body in requests

Tags: python, python-requests

Using Python's `requests` package, I have a body for a POST that has a bunch of `None` values, ex (dictionary, not JSON):

```
{
  'name': 'John',
  'surname': None,
  'somelist': [
    {
      'a': 1,
      'b': None
    },
    {
      'a': None,
      'b': 2
    }
  ],
  'otherdict': {
    'c': False,
    'd': None
  }
}
```

and I would like the actual body that gets sent out has all the entries with values `None` removed, as opposed to converted to JSON `null`:

```
{
  'name': 'John',
  'somelist': [
    {
      'a': 1
    },
    {
      'b': 2
    }
  ],
  'otherdict': {
    'c': False
  }
}
```

Does the `requests` package have an option that does this or do I need to do it on my end?

Comment: Note: The reason I'm asking this is b/c the web service doesn't conform to the REST API and needs string value `'null'` instead of JSON value `null` and these are all optional values, so it's easier for me to just not include them than to convert `None` to string `'null'`.

Comment: No such param in `requests`, also no such function in it. You need to convert None to 'null' by yourself

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with recursion (remove keys with `None` values or recursively call the `clean` method if the value is not `None`):

```
def clean(d):
    if type(d) == list:
        return [clean(e) for e in d]
    elif type(d) == dict:
        for k, v in list(d.items()):
            if v is None:
                del d[k]
            else:
                d[k] = clean(v)
    return d

print(clean(data))
```

**Output**

```
{'somelist': [{'a': 1}, {'b': 2}], 'otherdict': {'c': False}, 'name': 'John'}
```

Comment: Yeah, I figured as much.  Just wated to check if the requests package already has an option to do it so I don' t have to.  If not, I'll prolly use your code snippet.